# Внесение изменений в модель почему-то возвращает unicode

Tags: python, django

Добрый день, делаю редактирование формы со страницы и при сохранении новое значение почему-то сохраняется в unicode, после чего выводиться как `(u'Ivanov',) (u'Ivan',) (u'Ivanovich',)`, а требуется просто `Ivanov Ivan Ivanovich`

html:

```
{% if edit_note %}
<div id="editNote" class="newNote" style="display: block;">
<form action="/notebook/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
<input type="submit" value="Изменить запить № {{ edit_note.id }}">
<input type="hidden" name="edit_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="num_note" value="{{ edit_note.id }}">
<p>
<label for="id_surname">фамилия:</label>
<input id="id_surname" type="text" name="surname" maxlength="100" value={{ edit_note.surname }}>
</p>
<p>
<label for="id_name">имя:</label>
<input id="id_name" type="text" name="name" maxlength="100" value={{ edit_note.name }}>
</p>
<p>
<label for="id_fathername">отчество:</label>
<input id="id_fathername" type="text" name="fathername" maxlength="100"  value={{ edit_note.fathername }}>
</p>
</form>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

[views.py](http://views.py):

```
if request.method == "POST" and request.POST['edit_note'] == '1':
    nn = Notebook.objects.get(id = request.POST['num_note'])
    nn.surname    = request.POST['surname'],
    nn.name       = request.POST['name'],
    nn.fathername = request.POST['fathername'],
    nn.save()
    return redirect('/notebook/')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    nn = Notebook.objects.get(id = request.POST['num_note'])
    nn.surname    = request.POST['surname'],
    nn.name       = request.POST['name'],
    nn.fathername = request.POST['fathername'],
    nn.save()
```

Предположительно проблема в запятых в конце строк.